# How to map a network share folder to a local folder in Windows without additional Apps

Tags: windows, networking, symlink, shared-directory, network-share

Lets say there is a shared folder: `\\server\share\folder1` containing `Folder2\file.ext`

I would like mount that folder to `c:\somePath\someFolder`

So that I can reference `c:\somePath\someFolder\Folder2\file.ext`

Best I can find is mounting to drive letter. :(

The access to the file is just an example. Let's just assume there are a few servers and a few files. Powershell or cmd is fine. Heck I would take cygwin too. :)

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to map a UNC path to a local folder on Windows 2003?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339220/is-there-a-way-to-map-a-unc-path-to-a-local-folder-on-windows-2003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cmd (run as as administrator) run the following command:

```
mklink /D c:\somePath\someFolder \\server\share\folder1
```